# Regex for replacing dashes with underscores in directory names and not the filenames

Tags: c#, regex, replace

The string example is:

```
/my/test-is/for-this/to/work-right.txt
```

should be:

```
/my/test_is/for_this/to/work-right.txt
```

Anyone want to flex their Regex-Fu muscles?

Comment: is a directory always present? i.e. is `work-right.txt` -> `work-right.txt` and/or `/work-right.txt` -> `/work-right.txt` valid examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really. It's much better to use [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) and friends:

```
var s = "/my/test-is/for-this/to/work-right.txt";
var result = Path.Combine(
     Path.GetDirectoryName(s).Replace("-", "_"),
     Path.GetFileName(s)
);
```

If your path uses `/` as the directory separator, you are running on Windows and you don't want it to be replaced by `\` you can simply undo the replacement afterwards:

```
// What I 'm really doing here is showing that these constants exist;
// read the manual to see what you can expect from them.
result = result.Replace(
    Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,
    Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar
);
```

Comment: OK, that was the initial route I went, but though may be it would be better to Regex it.  I guess sometimes it's better to just get some reassurance that you are on the right path.  I'll mark you as my answer.